# Is HyperSQL / HSQLDB database resistant to password attacks?

Tags: security, hsqldb, password-protection, hypersql

Is HyperSQL / HSQLDB resistant to password attack? The database is used in this scenario:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/somedb", "SA", "some_password");
```

Lets say, if some hacker tries to connect 1000 times in one second with invalid passwords, what will happen? HyperSQL will block that user? Does HyperSQL database has some security methods against password attacks - for example login delay after some failures?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just try it out locally? I can't seem to find whether it has a limit on the amount of login attempts, but you could try it out with a local instance of the database and just doing something like:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
    System.out.println("Trying to log in, try number " + i);
    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/fsdb", "SA", "some_password");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        System.out.println("Sleep was interrupted.");
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

**Edit:** your database server should probably not be open to connections from all external IP's anyways.

So if there's no reason to allow all external IP's to make connections to the database server, you should make a whitelist with the help of [this guide](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/listeners-chapt.html#lsc_acl).

Comment: Yes, now I have tried similar code - after 100 logins with wrong password - I can continue - no login delays, or blocking. So it means to break HyperSQL database password is very easy. Maybe there are some settings/property file where I can restrict failed logins, etc.?

Comment: Ernestas Gruodis: I've added some info about securing your HSQLDB server better.

Comment: OK, but let's imagine - some hacker's application was installed (by opening the mail attachment or other way) on computer, and it starts to break database password.. And then, after password is cracked, sends the data over the network. It would be nice to have the ability to block invalid login attempts.

Comment: You can also change the `SA` username to some randomly generated string so that it takes forever (trillions of attempts) for a brute force attack to succeed.